# How can I completely change the underlying disks on each Hadoop DataNode?

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs

I have `N` Hadoop DataNodes. Each has attached **two** 3TB volumes. Each volume is formatted with XFS. Each volume is configured as a data directory for the DataNode. Example:

```
$ df -Th
/dev/xvdb1     xfs       3.0T  2.0T  1.1T  65% /mnt/vol_a
/dev/xvdc1     xfs       3.0T  1.3T  1.8T  41% /mnt/vol_b

$ cat hdfs-site.xml
...
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/mnt/vol_a/hdfs/datanode,/mnt/vol_b/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
...
```

Goal: I want to replace the two 3 TB volumes *completely* with a new **logical volume** comprised of *different* disks, which I can then expand in the future.

Problem: For each node, assuming the *new* volume is attached, how do I fully migrate the old volume**s** to the new volume without breaking Hadoop (i.e. HDFS, DataNodes, NameNode, etc.)?

I'm aware of [Hadoop's Hot Swap capabilities](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsUserGuide.html#DataNode_Hot_Swap_Drive), but the documentation is a bit lacking and it doesn't explicitly state that it moves blocks from the old volumes to the new volumes.

I do **not** need to keep the cluster running. If I can stop everything and somehow copy all blocks, that's great.

Answer (score 0):

- If all the files in your cluster have 2+ replicas. It is safe to simply shutdown one DN at a time and replace the disks with new ones. HDFS will take care re-replication process. You need to wait the file blocks being fully replicated though after the DN restarts (i.e., by running `hdfs fsck`).
- Or you can run DataNode decommission process, to wait DataNode to move all blocks out of this machine. And after you restart this DataNode with new disks. You need to run `Balancer` to move some data back.

Up to today (Sep 2016), there is no official way to move ***all blocks*** from one disk to another disk. However, it is perfectly safe to just run `mv /mnt/vol_a/hdfs/datanode  /mnt/large_vol_c/hdfs/datanode` by yourself when the DataNode (or the cluster) is shutdown. And then configure `dfs.data.dir` to the new location.